# Is OnStart and OnStop called on the same thread?

Tags: c#, windows-services, thread-safety

Is there a guarantee that `OnStop` is called on the same thread as `OnStart`? I am asking because I allocate resources in `OnStart` and I dispose them in `OnStop`. Without such guarantee I should add memory fence before accessing fields of my service.

Comment: There's a guarantee that `OnStop` won't be called until after `OnStart` has returned.  In practice, I'm pretty sure that means that if they aren't called from the same thread there will already be a memory fence between them, since one thread would have to communicate with the other one.  I don't know that there's any *formal* guarantee, though.  If this worries you, a full memory fence at the end of `OnStart` and/or the beginning of `OnStop` will have no measurable performance impact.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, it is not a matter of performance, after all service will be working longer than just mere fence, but I prefer writing code being aware what I am doing and not sprinkling it with various features "just in case" :-).

Comment: The .NET wrapper (ServiceBase) uses the threadpool to make calls to OnStart/OnStop.  It is not entirely obvious to me why they preferred doing it this way, this is not documented code.  But good enough to know that you don't have to worry about it, starting a tp thread provides an implicit full barrier.